# Is there any real reason to use a UiSearchBar over a Uitextfield?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was curious if I would be able to use a Uitextfield instead of a UiSearchBar because of the ease of resizing and the look. 
Are there any real drawbacks?

Comment: Consider leaving a nice comment, reason for downvoting, which I don't see here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is no real drawback to use `UITExtField` as an `UISearchBar`. You just only need to add `UITableView`,`UISearchBar` datasource and Delegate methods.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
     if (textField == your textfield) 
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    yourtableview.hidden = NO;
    return YES; 
}

}
return  YES;
}
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
     //....
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
     //...
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
     //...
}
```

Comment: And, how is this related to the `UITableView`?

Comment: check updated answer in textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField you can show table view when you start entering text in your textfield.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, no, no such reasons. **Depends on what you are going to do**. `UISearchBar` is more optimized for searching, with its' look, functions, and callback methods. If you have to create custom interface element for searching, you would better start with `UITextField` with a few `UIButton`s, `UISegmentedControl`s, whatever it takes.